# TLS1.3 using no cipher?

Tags: tls, openssl, ciphers

I received a spam text message and interrogated the domain name:

```
$ openssl s_client -servername https://example.com -connect example.com:443
```

What I want to know, is how likely it is that I should see the following

> write:errno=0
> no peer certificate available
> No client certificate CA names sent
> SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and
> written 301 bytes
> Verification: OK
> New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
> Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
> Compression: NONE
> Expansion: NONE
> No ALPN negotiated
> Early data was not sent
> Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Cipher = none? That seems very suspicious to me. As far as I know, the encryption aspect is the only part that actually secures against manipulation. Am I talking to who I think I'm talking to?

Comment: Welcome to the community. I would assume that there is no SSL certificate meaning that the connection is unencrypted and over HTTP. That doesn't mean much I think, even if most serious websites use HTTPS (meaning uses SSL certificates).

Comment: The first line of the session display for a good connection is "New, {protocol}, Cipher is {ciphersuite}" -- thus that first "(NONE)" _before_ Cipher means there was no handshake (as Steffen also confirms from "handshake has read 0") and since the ciphersuite is a _result_ of the handshake with no handshake it is completely impossible for there to be a ciphersuite. This is like if you have no children then you can't fill in their age(s) on your tax return because people who don't exist don't have an age.

Answer (score 4):

There are likely more messages which you did not include in your question. But obviously the server did not even reply, just closed the connection:

```
write:errno=0
...
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and
written 301 bytes
```

This means there was no successful TLS handshake.

Apart from that the `-servername` argument should only be the hostname, not a URL. I.e. instead of

```
$ openssl s_client -servername https://dom.ain -connect dom.ain:443
```

use

```
$ openssl s_client -servername dom.ain -connect dom.ain:443
```

Comment: You are correct. I had an omission of: (line #1: "CONNECTED(00000003)")